# Get a list of all the function signatures that have been compiled for a generic function

Tags: julia

The Julia JIT compiler compiles separate versions of generic functions for each unique function signature that gets called at the REPL. For example, if `foo` is defined as

```
foo(x, y) = (x * y) ^ 2
```

then calling `foo(2, 3)` and `foo("a", "b")` will compile two different versions of `foo` that correspond to the signatures `foo(::Int, ::Int)` and `foo(::String, ::String)`, respectively. Is there a way to get a list of the different function signatures that have been compiled for a generic function?

I know about the `methods` function, but `methods` only lists the methods of a generic function that have been written by the programmer. And, of course, as the `foo` example above demonstrates, one method written by a programmer can spawn many separate compiled functions.

I'm just asking this for educational purposes. I don't have any code in which I plan to use the results of a hypothetical function that shows all the function signatures that have been compiled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [MethodAnalysis](https://github.com/timholy/MethodAnalysis.jl) package has tools for this and much more. For example:

```
julia> foo(x, y) = (x * y) ^ 2
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(1,1); foo(1.0, 1);

julia> using MethodAnalysis

julia> methodinstances(foo)
2-element Vector{Core.MethodInstance}:
 MethodInstance for foo(::Int64, ::Int64)
 MethodInstance for foo(::Float64, ::Int64)
```

In some cases the specializations are not an `svec`, `methodinstances` makes it more straightforward to collect them in an easy-to-access format.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps there is a nicer way but this for sure works:

```
julia> foo(1,1);

julia> foo(1.0, 1);

julia> typeof(foo).name.mt.defs.func.specializations
svec(MethodInstance for foo(::Int64, ::Int64), MethodInstance for foo(::Float64, ::Int64), #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef, #undef)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to make sure it's mentioned here:

There is another package called [LookingGlass.jl](https://github.com/NHDaly/LookingGlass.jl), which is quite similar to [MethodAnalysis.jl](https://github.com/timholy/MethodAnalysis.jl), and provides a function for this too:

```
julia> foo(x, y) = (x * y) ^ 2
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(1,1); foo(1.0, 1);

julia> using LookingGlass

julia> LookingGlass.func_specializations(foo)
Dict{Core.MethodInstance,Method} with 2 entries:
  MethodInstance for foo(::Float64, ::Int64) => foo(x, y) in Main at REPL[4]:1
  MethodInstance for foo(::Int64, ::Int64)   => foo(x, y) in Main at REPL[4]:1
```

I've wanted to merge LookingGlass.jl together with MethodAnalysis.jl for quite some time, but always too busy.

LookingGlass has other runtime reflection analysis tools, for modules, and functions, and methods, but I think the implementations in MethodAnalysis for this task are more robust, so @tholy's answer is probably best.